# Listing of research salesforce1

Tags: list-view, search

I need to change the views of the research in salesforce1 because if you search only appears the recent listing. However I need to see the whole list, ie to view all. 
It is possible to change the view and if possible how can I do this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to research but used to be a limitation of Salesforce1 in general that it showed only recent records and not all records.

This has been [delivered and fixed](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ky69AAA) in Summer 14 release. And as per this [thread](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/05/salesforce-summer-14-release.html), you should already have access to Summer 14

Comment: hello. Thanks for your help. 
Maybe I did not make myself clear. I'll give an example: 
I have in my business salesforce1 an object that has a Lookup to the object car. When I click on the magnifying glass to choose a car, this just shows me the cars that I've visualized. 
It is possible to change this so I see them all? 

Thank you !!!